# Headless Edge driven through Selenium by C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge, headless-browser, selenium-edgedriver

Given that Selenium can drive the Edge browser for programming automated testing in C#, as noted in this article:

https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/

Is it possible to run it in headless mode? If so, how?

Comment: [No](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14057655/). But there is a How: [Vote for it](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/6545168-headless-browser-for-testing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by `@Tewr`, no: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14057655/ but the feature can be requested: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/6545168-headless-browser-for-testing

*NB: I find it very odd that this isn't a tent pole feature.*

Comment: both links are dead :(