# how to properly call the edge browser with selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, microsoft-edge

The target of this project is to automate checking sites with Microsoft edge browser using selenium-python i downloaded the webdriver for the edge legacy from [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)  and i went for the latest release 17134 extracted it with out any problems now lets say i want to visit facebook in an automated way with firefox using the geckodriver

firefox code sample with selenium

```
from  selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# setting up headless option for faster execution
options = Options()
options.headless = True


browser = (webdriver.Firefox(options=options))
browser.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
```

but when I try to use Microsoft edge that is built in windows 10 I get an attribute error

```
from  selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options



options = Options()
options.headless = True

#browser = webdriver.edge(options=options)
browser = webdriver.edge()
```

ps : when I uncomment this part (browser = webdriver.edge(options=options)) I get module not found error

what is the right way to call Microsoft edge browser , or what I am doing wrong

Comment: This should be `broswer=webdriver.Edge()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using this [WebDriver](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager) Package. Works perfectly. This package auto-download and runs your system-compatible browser smoothly. If you want to install and run a specific version, that is also possible. To know the instructions [click here](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager#get-browser-version-from-path).

> This code is for Selenium 4 [Python 3.10.*]

```
  class MyEdge:
      def get_browser(self):
          options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
          # If you want to avoid popup browser use '--headless'
          options.add_argument('--headless')
          # Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=python#using-chromium-specific-options
          self.driver = webdriver.Edge(options= options,service=Service(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()))
          return self.driver
```

> **More optional arguments:**
> --headless, --no-sandbox, '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1280x1696', '--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data', '--hide-scrollbars', '--enable-logging', '--log-level=0', , '--single-process', '--data-path=/tmp/data-path', '--ignore-certificate-errors', '--homedir=/tmp', '--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir'

Make sure to impore:

```
# Import
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
```

Answer (score 5):

when I use Edge and try to make Edge headless. I also find it hard to do that with slight changes as Chrome. And I refer to the official documentation and get a official solution. Besides selenium, you need to install `msedge-selenium-tools`, just pip install it`pip install msedge-selenium-tools`. And use `Edge` Class in msedge tools. Just like:

```py
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge
driver = Edge(executable_path='where')
```

And if we want to make Edge headless, we need to use `EdgeOptions` Class which selenium.webdriver doesn't offer. selenium.webdriver only provides us with ChromeOptions, FirefoxOptions and Ie's. EdgeOptions is in a separated package `msedge.selenium_tools`.Then we add argument as what we do on Firefox or Chrome. Before that, we need to set the attribute **use_chromium** as True. The whole codes:

```py
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge

# make Edge headless
edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True  # if we miss this line, we can't make Edge headless
# A little different from Chrome cause we don't need two lines before 'headless' and 'disable-gpu'
edge_options.add_argument('headless')
edge_options.add_argument('disable-gpu')

driver = Edge(executable_path='where', options=edge_options)
```

Hope it helps. Sorry for my awkward explaination.

Comment: does this require edge chromium to work, i would love to run this with out installing any additional browsers

Comment: @WeedCookie The old Edge browser? will be going out of support anyway. I assume you are wanting to test on the old one that may well not be security patched?

Answer (score 0):

I try to refer to the official documentation for WebDriver for Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML). But I did not get any information about the **Headless** mode in it.

[WebDriver (EdgeHTML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver)

I also try to refer to some old threads to find any information on this topic. It looks like we cannot use the Headless mode with the MS Edge legacy browser.

[Headless Edge driven through Selenium by C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382059/headless-edge-driven-through-selenium-by-c-sharp)

I found one article that also said that 'User cannot use IE10, IE11, Edge, Opera & Safari for headless testing.'

[Headless Browsers Testing using Selenium Webdriver](https://vsplc.com/headless-browsers-testing-using-selenium-webdriver/)

From the above references, it looks like you cannot use Headless mode with the MS Edge legacy browser.

As a workaround, I suggest you try to make a test with the MS Edge Chromium browser. I found that it supports Headless mode.

[Using Chromium-Specific Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium#using-chromium-specific-options)

Comment: the problem i am facing is that i can't change the options of the webdriver to make it headless if i include options inside the brackets i get  a typeerror unexpected keyword argument options

Comment: Please see the updated answer. It may help to clarify the issue. Let me know if you have further questions.